# Center Map based on Route

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to center a Google Map based on the center-point of the route, but I cannot use `fitbounds` because it doesn't allow me to use a custom zoom (it zooms to the bounds of the route).

The following is my current attempt. I wonder if it is possible to use map.setCenter? I have commented out the line that I think I need help with.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(dr, 'directions_changed', function() {
  var route = dr.getDirections().routes[0];
  var path = route.overview_path;
  es.getElevationAlongPath({
    path: path,
    samples: Math.max(50, path.length * 2)
  }, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
      drawElevation(result);
      recalcHeight();
      if (fitBounds) {
        map.setZoom(route.bounds);
       //map.setCenter();
        fitBounds = false;

      }
    }
    else {
      $('#error').text(status).show();
    }
    recalcHeight();
  });
});
```

**Update**: this simple change solved my problem - custom zoom followed by correct centering:

```
map.setZoom(13);
map.setCenter(route.bounds.getCenter());
```

**Second Update:** Please remove the the vote downs.  This was a legitimate question that had an easy answer.

Comment: What do you consider the "center-point of the route" - halfway between east-west and north-south extremes? Why do you not want to use `fitbounds`?

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem. That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y (centermap on route center)  would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y.

Comment: @Floris fitbounds will not allow me to set a custom zoom.

Comment: @ErikPhilips what do you suggest, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DirectionsRoute has a `bounds`-property(a `LatLngBounds`-object). `LatLngBounds` have a `center`-property, so all you need to do is to set the `center` of the map to the `center` of the `bounds` of  `route`:

```
map.setCenter(route.bounds.getCenter());
```

Comment: that did not seem to center the map, @Dr.Molle

Comment: What else does it do in your opinion?

Comment: This part of your code : `map.setZoom(route.bounds);` is wrong, results in an error and stops the further script-execution. You may write `map.setZoom('need coffee');` with the same effect.

Comment: Are you going to leave me guessing why it is wrong? :D @Dr.Molle

Comment: `setZoom()` expects an integer as argument, not a LatLngBounds(that's what `route.bounds` is)

Comment: Enjoyed reading the very polite comment stream as much as seeing the right solution!

Comment: @Floris Thank  you.  Do you want to give this a thumbs up so I can regain some of those reputation points? :)

Comment: I didn't give your question a downvote... and happy to give an upvote. I agree it seems a legitimate question - you worked hard to create a question that could be answered, and the information we ended up with will help the community. Not sure what made people go all negative.

Answer (score 2):

If you display a Google Map on your site using the Google JS API, here is how you can have it auto-centered and auto-zoomed depending on the markers it contains.

Before adding markers:

`bounds  = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();`

Everytime you add a new marker:

`loc = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.position.lat(),marker.position.lng());`
`bounds.extend(loc);`

After all markers have been added:

`map.fitBounds(bounds);       # auto-zoom
 map.panToBounds(bounds);     # auto-center`

That's it, cheers.

I found it from here: [Link](https://coderwall.com/p/hojgtq/auto-center-and-auto-zoom-a-google-map)